# Git push to remote but cannot pull from local

Tags: git

I have one git repository on a local server.
I want to clone my project to a server that cannot access to Internet. (only SSH available).
I cloned my project, then copied it on the Webserver "dev".

I added a "dev" git remote.

Let's say I just did a new commit that adds a new file.

When I do on the local server

```
 git push dev master
```

It pushes everything to the remote server. Then I do

```
 git log
```

on the remote server, and i see the last commit in the log, but the new file does not appear in the folder.

When I do on the remote server

```
git status

# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
```

But those commits were not applied on the remote server.

I can't do

```
 git pull
```

as the server cannot access internet and that it couldn't anyways pull from the local server.

What command could I do to apply the changes on the remote server ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: if you say a push is dome to remote server that means remote has Internet access. On the other hand you have said that remote has no Internet access. Which one is true ??

Comment: try `git merge origin/master` instead of pull

Comment: It has internet access so ssh works, but the ssh user cannot ping anything nor access to any internet resource.

Comment: Oh, wait. You are pushing to non-bare repository. Do you see a warning message? Anyway read this: http://wekeroad.com/2011/09/17/deploying-a-site-with-git-hooks http://ryanflorence.com/deploying-websites-with-a-tiny-git-hook/

Comment: Thank you very much @kan it worked;) That was really easy! You can post it as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 1):

You are pushing to non-bare repository. Do you see a warning message?

Anyway read this:

[wekeroad.com/2011/09/17/deploying-a-site-with-git-hooks](http://wekeroad.com/2011/09/17/deploying-a-site-with-git-hooks) and

[ryanflorence.com/deploying-websites-with-a-tiny-git-hook](http://ryanflorence.com/deploying-websites-with-a-tiny-git-hook)